# Is there a way to log x and y using Paraview?

Tags: python, widget, paraview

I had tried to create a simple mouse event to see if it would work in a test Python code and now I'm trying it in my actual code.
Is there a way for me to create a mouse event that logs the x and y points of the windows in a paraview widget? If so how would I do it?
I am creating a program that takes a png and displays it in 3d using paraview widget.

Comment: could you please provide a minimal code snippet to illustrate what you want to do?

Comment: Sure this is what i'm currently working with. class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('ParaView in Qt Widget')

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.pv_widget = ParaViewWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.pv_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: def load_sample_dataset(self):
        # Load a sample dataset (replace with your own data loading code)
        dataset = pv.read('Example.PNG')

        # Add the dataset to the ParaView render window
        self.interactor.add_mesh(dataset, show_edges=True)

        # Reset the camera position
        self.interactor.reset_camera()

        self.interactor.update()

    def update_mouse_position(self, x, y):
        # Update the mouse position label with the current coordinates
        self.mouse_position_label.setText(f"Mouse Position: ({x}, {y})")

Comment: def show(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_updated is False:
            super(ParaViewWidget, self).show(*args, **kwargs)

    def build_ui(self):
        """Grunt work to make the UI

        NOTE THIS IS FIRST TIME ONLY, call update_ui if data changes

        TODO
        lots to do.
        """
        return

    def update_ui(self):
        """
        required for TRI standard practice
        called by parent widget
        :return:
        """
        return